# WP8 App Bar colored IconButton Image?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, msdn

I am creating app bar in WP8 app. I need to give colored image like profile picture in `ApplicationBarIconButton`.

As per [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff431806(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_IconButtonBestPractices) : Icon images should use a white foreground on a transparent background using an alpha channel

But, I have not found any official link saying that it is not possible to do that.

Your replies are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. Framework uses appbar icon as a bitmask to create white theme icon automatically. This is why it should be white on transparent.